# Can quick lawn grass seed be used for overseeding?

Tags: lawn, grass, seeds, lawn-repair

I want to overseed my lawn to thicken it up.

I have a lot of quicklawn grass seed, which is designed for new lawns grown from scratch.

It seems to me that, in the most part, a seed is a seed and this stuff will do just fine.
My question is, is there anything wrong with using this seed for over seeding, rather than a 'designed for purpose' overseeding seed pack?

Answer (score 3):

The quick lawn seed contains mostly fast growing annual grass.  The purpose of that grass is to protect the perennial grass and help it take hold.

You can look at the back of the seed bag and it will tell you which types of grass are in the mix.  Most quick mixtures have a mix of rye grass and perennial grass (blue grass, fescue, etc).

For overseeding, there are mixtures specifically deigned for the purpose.  You can also get sunny/shady blends that have grasses that are better suited for those growing conditions so you'd be better off using one of those or mixing it with your quick lawn.  My feeling is that if the lawn is already well established, throwing the quick lawn on there is probably a waste of time.